# Which .NET components use the Dispatcher?

Tags: .net, wpf, dispatcher

I am creating extra threads for performing various background actions. If I use WPF inside that worker thread then I need to ensure that the Dispatcher for that thread is shutdown gracefully to prevent memory leaks. Are there other .NET components that use the Dispatcher? Or is WPF the only .NET component that uses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of your question, you're creating a `Dispatcher` on your background threads rather than capturing and using the existing one from your main UI thread. Why do you do this? Your background threads should just use the existing `Dispatcher` and allow the UI thread to handle clean up of it.

Comment: The background thread is creating a report by using WPF to setup a visual tree and then rendering that visual tree to a bitmap that is then saved to disk. I found it was leaking memory and only then discovered that WPF uses a dispatcher to handle memory management. Adding a Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Run() and shutting it down before exiting the thread removes the memory leak.

Wondered if there are any other areas, such as WCF?, that use the dispather and so I need to be aware of that as a potential leak as well.

Comment: It's actually a service that has many reports generated this way based on scheduling and getting the relevant data from a database. So there is no main UI thread involved.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatcher internally uses SynchronizationContext, which is a traditional class, used in windows for cross thread operations. But the "Dispatcher" is only related to WPF.